# Firebase - Facebook Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm struggling to get my simple Facebook login to work. I'm simply trying to follow the example on the website but I run into this error:

`Uncaught: L {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "signInWithPopup failed: First argument "authProvider" must be a valid Auth provider."}`

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
export const createUserWithFacebook = () => {
  let provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  firebaseApp.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // firebaseApp.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
  });
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your firebase instance of the Facebook provider object should be:

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
```

this `new` will use firebase own constructor for the new instance.

instead of :

```
let provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
```

here the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) further details